# Smallest AVL tree such that successive insertions causes all four cases of rotations

Tags: avl-tree

I am supposed to build an AVL tree using insertions of integer values, starting from scratch, such that all four cases of tree rotations (simple left, simple right, double left and double right) occur after successive insertions. I suppose it is not that much work exhibiting such an example, but going about finding a minimal example and proving that the example found is the smallest seems a bit more difficult. Does anyone know how to proceed? That double rotations should occur puts some constraints regarding the minimal height of the tree, at least.

Comment: Are you asking what order to enter numbers into the tree? Just think about it...

Comment: Well, should I just use brute force to see what kind of tree is the smallest? I can see that getting gritty pretty quickly.

Comment: Since I can't edit my last comment, I post a new one. I suppose that I should find the smallest tree such that (for instance) if I insert a number $x_1$ into the tree, then that requires a left rotation for rebalancing, upon which insertion of a certain value $x_2$ requires (for instance) a double right rotation, etc. A specific sequence of values should be exhibited.
Well, should I just use brute force to see what kind of tree is the smallest? I can see that getting gritty pretty quickly. Or maybe there is some shortcut - using, for instance, fibonacci trees.

Comment: Do you consider a double right as a single left followed by a single right on the parent node?

Comment: The fact that double rotations may be implemented as combinations of single rotations is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter which rotation you start with, you'll always need 3 nodes to cause the first rotation, and you'll always end up with a balanced tree at that point. Once a tree is balanced, you need a minimum of 2 nodes to cause another imbalance.

---

Values are random.

**Single right**

50, 25, 10

**Double right**

5, 8

**Single left**

75, 100

**Double left**

63, 55

Can visualize here https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html

Small implementation detail, but a double rotation is simply a combination of two, opposite single rotations.

Comment: I don't think that this is right based in my interpretation of the problem. For instance, every other value being inserted here doesn't cause an imbalance.

Comment: I can promise you this is the smallest tree. 3 consecutive inserts are needed for the first rotation, then at least 2 consecutive inserts are needed at each leaf to cause each other rotation.

Comment: So, how would you prove that this is indeed a minimal example?

Comment: I just explained it in the previous comment... No matter which rotation you start with, you'll always need 3 nodes to cause the first rotation, and you'll always end up with a balanced tree at that point. Once a tree is balanced, you need a minimum of 2 nodes to cause another imbalance.